# nginx redirecting to localhost

Tags: nginx, redirect, localhost

I'm sort of a noob at this and I'm just switching into nginx so I apologize for the noob question.

I have installed nginx and when I go to the root directory of its web folder I can get the index file. But when I try to go to a folder, say, server.ip.address/folder, it will go to localhost/folder.

How can I stop it from doing this? I have added server_name_in_redirect off in the "default" file in sites-available.

Configuration file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#

Blockquote

 mail {
#     # See sample authentication script at:
#     # http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#     # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#     # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#     # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#     server {
#         listen     localhost:110;
#         protocol   pop3;
#         proxy      on;
#     }
# 
#     server {
#         listen     localhost:143;
#         protocol   imap;
#         proxy      on;
#     }
# }
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts

server {
    listen   80 default;
    server_name  localhost;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/nginx-default;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /doc {
        root   /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location /images {
        root   /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
    }

    #error_page  404  /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    #}

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
        #proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #includefastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
        #deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#listen   8000;
#listen   somename:8080;
#server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#location / {
#root   html;
#index  index.html index.htm;
#}
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#listen   443;
#server_name  localhost;

#ssl  on;
#ssl_certificate  cert.pem;
#ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
#ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

#location / {
#root   html;
#index  index.html index.htm;
#}
#}
```

Comment: Please provide your configuration file.

Comment: I have provided them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
server_name  localhost;
```

to

```
server_name  your.domain.com;
```

Comment: Thank you! Strangely enough, I tried this before but it didn't work.

Comment: @richard, i was just doing this, and none of my changes really were reflected in my browser until i cleared my cache. even though i was restarting nginx

Answer (score 5):

You'll need the above answer plus

```
server_name_in_redirect off;
```

Then clear your browser cache

Answer (score 1):

To complete the above answers

change

```
server_name  localhost;
```

to

```
server_name  your.domain.com;
```

Plus add the following line to the nginx config file

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```